# Undefined type 'Laravel\Cashier\Cashier'.intelephense(1009)

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel I want to integrate subscription module in my project as I followed the following process till now.

1. `composer require laravel/cashier`
2. `php artisan vendor:publish --tag="cashier-migrations"`
3. Update User Model

```
    use Laravel\Cashier\Billable;
    
    class User extends Authenticatable
    {
        use Billable;
    }
```

4. `.env`

   CASHIER_MODEL=App\Models\User

---

Need suggestions where I am going wrong.

[image: Undefined Laravel/Cashier/Cashier]

Comment: Sometimes the intelephense doesnt recognize the newly installed packages, the way I get it to work is by closing the IDE, and reopening it again. then the error doesnt show up anymore

Answer (score 5):

I also had the same problem. I closed my IDE and restarted it and the error was gone. - sharad paudel

EDIT: I can confirm that restarting VS Code is a solution to this problem. I'm also using Laravel / Cashier, and I came across a similar situation. VS Code was giving me the red squiggly lines inside the actual Billable trait file: `src/vendor/laravel/cashier/src/Billable.php`
similar to the OP. It seems like it isn't an "error" so much as a minor confusion in VS Code - I had all the correct "use" import lines.
After restarting VS Code, all file associations seemed to be fine, and all the red squiggles were gone.
I have also seen this happen before, after installing something with "composer", a restart was needed to make VS Code happy. -dogatonic

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31861233)

Answer (score 1):

Add `Billable` after using the comma (`,`); use `HasApiTokens`, `HasFactory`, `Notifiable`. Write it like

```
use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable, Billable;
```

Comment: Thanks it got resolved.